# open word document (saved as binary) from database

Tags: c#, sql-server, ms-word

I'm making a program with c# and sql server and I have a problem , I hope if anyone help me .

I will but the database on pc and the program will be installed in other PCs , and app pcs' program connected to that database.

the program saving documents (word -excel) as binary ,using this code:

```
  byte[] ReadFile(string sPath)
    {
        //Initialize byte array with a null value initially.
        byte[] data = null;

        //Use FileInfo object to get file size.
        FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(sPath);
        long numBytes = fInfo.Length;

        //Open FileStream to read file
        FileStream fStream = new FileStream(sPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        //Use BinaryReader to read file stream into byte array.
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fStream);

        //When you use BinaryReader, you need to supply number of bytes to read from file.
        //In this case we want to read entire file. So supplying total number of bytes.
        data = br.ReadBytes((int)numBytes);
        return data;
    }

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string dt = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString();

        byte[] red = ReadFile(textBox3.Text);
        con.Open();
        string qry = "insert into documents ([Account no],Name,[Phone number],Date,[Document name],Document,Type) values(@accon,@name,@phone,@date,@docname,@doc,@type)";

        //Initialize SqlCommand object for insert.
        SqlCommand SqlCom = new SqlCommand(qry, con);

        //We are passing Original Image Path and Image byte data as sql parameters.

        SqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@accon", textBox1.Text));
        SqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", textBox2.Text));
        SqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@phone", textBox3.Text));
        SqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@date", dt));
        SqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@docname", textBox1.Text));
         SqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@doc", (object)red));

        SqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@type", (object)textBox2.Text));
        SqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("done");
    }
```

the problem : that I don't know how to retrieve saved documents in database and open it with Microsoft word or Microsoft Excel according to their types.

I want to select specific document form database and open it

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you store in `Type` for Word and what for Excel?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
String connStr = "connection string";

// add here extension that depends on your file type
string fileName = Path.GetTempFileName() + ".doc";

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        // you have to distinguish here which document, I assume that there is an `id` column
        cmd.CommandText = "select document from documents where id = @id";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;
        using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                int size = 1024 * 1024;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                int readBytes = 0;
                int index = 0;

                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
                {
                    while ((readBytes = (int)dr.GetBytes(0, index, buffer, 0, size)) > 0)
                    {
                        fs.Write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
                        index += readBytes;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// open your file, the proper application will be executed because of proper file extension
Process prc = new Process();
prc.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
prc.Start();
```

Comment: Really I don't know how to thank you ,I spent a lot of time in this problem and I didn't find a suitable solution .
Thanks a lot :))))

Comment: @moonshine, there is no need to thank. Just accept (and up vote if you really like) the answer it's the same :-).

Comment: I accepted but voting need 15 reputation, I have only 11 reputation 
when I reach 15 I'll vote you for sure :)

Answer (score 0):

The crux is `Response.ContentType`:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";  // for excel
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-word";  // for word
Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";//for jpg images
```

It is advised to store content type also in database so that your code will be generic and can display/store any type of file

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader rdr = null;
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = null;
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand selcmd = null;
try
{
    conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(
        System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
        .ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    selcmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(
        "select pic1 from msg where msgid=" + Request.QueryString["imgid"],
        conn);

    conn.Open();
    rdr = selcmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
        Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])rdr["pic1"]);
    }
    if (rdr != null)
        rdr.Close();
}
finally
{
    if (conn != null)
        conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: thank you , it's useful advice
I tried this code and show this error
Error 1 The name 'Request' does not exist in the current context 

and I added System.web reference and using it

Comment: o i am so sorry !  you asked about windows app and i had given solution for web app.

Answer (score 0):

After you have retrieved your document from the database (or any type of storage you care to use on the server) you should save the document in the windows temporary folder (Path.GetSpecialFolder) and use the Word Interop library to start word (or excel using its own interop library) with the document you just saved.

```
var temporayFileName = Path.GetRandomFileName();
var temporaryFileStream = File.Open(temporaryFileName, FileMode.Create);
var memoryStream = documentRepository.Get(...);
memoryStream.CopyTo(temporaryFileStream);

// Word App
dynamic wordApp = new Application { Visible = true };
var doc = wordApp.Documents.Add(TemplateName);
templatedDocument.Activate();
```

(See this document for more information about starting and manipulating word: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff714583.aspx)
.

Comment: thank you , but I didn't save documents in the server 
I saved it as binary in database

Comment: It doesn't matter to this code how your documentRepository gets its document. Or is your question how to retrieve binary data?